# how to assign collection name to a variable so that I can insert data into It

Tags: c#, mongodb-atlas

I would like to insert document into collection in database inside MongoDB atlas cloud service through c# app.

I used answer from SO to help me create collection:

```
await database.CreateCollectionAsync("tableTest", new CreateCollectionOptions
            {
                Capped = true,
                MaxSize = 1024,
                MaxDocuments = 10,
            });
```

now I would like to insert data into collection but I dont know how to assign 
collection to some variable when its created this way..

I dont know collection name ?

```
await missingcollectionname???.InsertOneAsync(reader);
```

---

UPDATE:
here is how in my particular case:

```
await database.GetCollection<MongoDB.Bson.IO.JsonReader>("tableTest").InsertOneAsync(reader);
```

Comment: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_MongoDatabaseBase_GetCollection__1.htm

Comment: Please don't post code in comments; it's unreadable. I've never used MongoDB in my life; I just posted the result of 15 seconds of googling.

Comment: me neither :) i got it.